# How are filesystems mounted in Lion?

Tags: macos, mount

I posted a question a while back regarding network mounts.  But I have a more general question. If Lion no longer uses `/etc/fstab` how are standard mounts in addition to network mounts handled? I would like to be able to customize this.  For instance how is root mounted and such? Also for instance, how is removable media mounted?

Comment: FYI: OS X still respects fstab entries.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably a bit late for your uses, but my understanding is that this is determined by the file `/etc/auto_master`. You should read `auto_master`'s documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/auto_master.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/auto_master) or running `man auto_master` in the Terminal.